# Can I use these nuts to cap single 14 gauge wires?

Tags: wiring

The package says these nuts can handle the size range 2-18 to 2-14. Is a single 14AWG in that range?

This is going to be a temporary cap off for several months until house is painted and new pergola built. The wires feed porch lights.

[image: front of bag of nuts]

[image: back of bag of nuts]

Comment: The CE multipacks will include little blue ones, which twist nice and tight on a single 14awg.

Answer (score 12):

Minimum is two #18 AWG which would be .00256 sq.in.  One #14 AWG is .00323 sq. in.  and is less than two #14 AWG so you'll be fine using those wire nuts.

Comment: This may be the most significant-digit complete answer I've seen here! ;)

Comment: This doesn't take into account the insulator. I find that a nut on a single conductor holds **WAY** better if you don't strip the wire. (obviously only applies to single conductors:-))

Answer (score 6):

1 #14 should be just fine. Worst case, twist it as tightly as you can and then add a piece of electrical tape to hold it on.

In general, I think wire nuts don't list *1* of anything because they are officially called wire **connectors**. If you have only one, you are not *connecting* anything together. But they can certainly work well with one wire as a protector, particularly if that wire is not at the low end of the range for that particular wire nut - e.g., I would not use this for a single #18.

*See also: "The sound of one hand clapping"*

Answer (score 4):

Max is 2-14.  1-14 is less.

It might do two 14 gauge wires, but really most people would suggest a larger size nut if at the max.

One 14 gauge will be at the sweet spot for those nuts.

Comment: The diameter may be in range, but you really have to pay attention to the stripped wire length when putting a wire nut on only one wire. When you have multiple conductors twisting together into a spiral, they end up taking less linear length than their stripped length. That doesn't happen with a single conductor.